# How to synchnorize files with mobile phone running LineageOS?

Tags: android, rsync, data-synchronization, lineageos

I have a mobile phone running LineageOS 16.0. I would like to organize the automatic synchronization of particular directory on mobile phone with some remote directory (e.g. exposed via FTP/SMB/SSH) on the server. Ideally would be to have an option either to make one-way (synchronize only missing files) or two-way (source and target are identical after synchronization) modes.

In particular above can be achieved by using the [`rsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) utility. I see the following options:

#### Mobile phone is exposing the folder via e.g. SSH

This would require LineageOS running SSH server. In this case `rsync` could be run on the server (periodically or on some event).

- Is SSHD server already installed on LineageOS ([Native SSH server on LinageOS](https://binfalse.de/2018/09/06/native-ssh-server-on-linageos/))? If not, is it possible to install it from a package?
- Will running in the background `sshd` daemon drain the mobile battery?
- How difficult would be to add it to startup ([SSHD on LineageOS](https://lisas.de/%7Ealex/?p=237), [Execute Script on Start Up](https://h4des.org/blog/index.php?/archives/359-Android-LineageOS-16-Execute-Script-on-Start-Up.html))?

#### Mobile phone is running rsync

- This requires [`rsync` installation to LineageOS](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_external_rsync). Maybe there is ready-to-use package or will it require the compilation?
- I would need an icon (or some other easy way) to execute `rsync` on mobile. How to organize that?

If you see other more handy/easy options, please describe how to setup/organize them.

P.S. Dropbox or any other cloud solutions is not an option (out of scope for this question).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I use the FolderSync app for this (it supports connecting to an SSH server at scheduled intervals, although I personally use it with Nextcloud). Syncthing is also a good solution I've used in the past, although you'll need to install that on your server also (no cloud required).

Trying to run an rsync server on a phone doesn't sound appealing, but there are a couple of rsync client apps in the play store.